# C# OpenFileDialog performance improvement

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, parallel-processing, openfiledialog

I am curently loading from 10k to 200k files, so I am looking for some performance boost here.

Here is how I am doing this:

```
        List<string> myFiles = new List<string>();
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
        openFileDialog.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            foreach (string filename in openFileDialog.FileNames)
            {
                myFiles.Add(filename);

            }
        }
        string[] files = myFiles.ToArray();
        Splitter(files);

        private void Splitter(string[] file)
        {
            try
            {
                tempDict = file
                    .SelectMany(i => File.ReadAllLines(i)
                    .SelectMany(line => line.Split(new[] { ' ', ',', '.', '?', '!', }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)))                    
                    .GroupBy(word => word)
                    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Ex(ex);
            }
        }
```

I was thinking about making foreach pararell:

```
        Parallel.ForEach(openFileDialog.FileNames, filename =>
            {
                mySpam.Add(filename);
            });
```

Is it safe? Are there any more improvements in this code to be made? Right now, it gets laggy and program "freezes" while loading those files, so it would be nice if it was doing those things "behind scenes". I am using WPF and the loading files begins after button click.

Comment: Have you considered rewriting solution to standard algorithm rather than using Linq? This would help you see what are the bottlenecks and give you much more freedom in implementing optimizations.
You are counting all the distinct words in all of the files?

Comment: Also, the Linq is processing all files at once that could also lead to memory problems - and processing everything at once is not necessary at all, you should process files one by one and build result.

Comment: @Dusan so I should change the Splitter method? Didn't think about problem there.. hmm.

Comment: I'd profile the app first, e.g. with [Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385749.aspx), so that you would see exactly where the bottleneck is. [ETW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968803%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is also a neat tool for performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. You're probably bottlenecking on IO, however, you might get a better speed by parallelizing part of the query:

```
file
    //ReadLines is non-greedy equiv of ReadAllLines
    //best to do this on a single thread...
    .SelectMany(i => File.ReadLines(i))
    //now go parallel.
    .AsParallel()
    .SelectMany(line => line.Split(new[] { ' ', ',', '.', '?', '!', },
                        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))                   
    .GroupBy(word => word)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

Comment: Yeah, I am also thinking that LOADING of that many files is the bigger problem, not the instructions itself. But I may be wrong.

Comment: Unless you've got some amazing bit of storage kit, you won't speed up loading files with parallellization. You'll just cause a bunch of disk thrashing which will slow down your reads, not speed them up. In my experience, you'll get better performance by doing your IO reads from a single thread.

Comment: I'll check it with Stopwatch method. Thanks for comment

Answer (score 0):

You can try these things:

1. As Dusan suggested, convert it to a standard algorithm so that you can time the different parts of the algorithm and see which is taking more time.
2. Move the processing to a background thread instead of the UI thread. That will keep your UI responsive.
3. Try Parallel.For / Parallel.ForEach or Select.AsParallel (Plinq) to perform action parallelly. Keep in mind thread safety. Also when you do this operation in parallel, number of CPU cores and the disk throughput will matter.
4. See if Regex will help instead of manual string manipulation.